# How did they switch Benji with real Solomon?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

In the scene that IMF is meeting with Alan Hunley in *Mission: Impossible - Fallout*, Hunt asks Benji to play Solomon Lane, by wearing a mask. Then the scene is shown that Luther is helping Benji wear the mask, and **clearly** shows that the one leaving the room is Benji, not the real Solomon. Also, Walker is watching the room from the laptop.

But turns out they somehow switched the real Solomon with Benji. How did this happen?

Comment: The real question should be: _why didn't the real Solomon warn Walker?_ Not in an obvious way, just asking where are they taking him would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

> ..and **clearly** shows that the one leaving the room is Benji, not the real Solomon.

Since Benji in the mask is *identical* to Solomon this is not the case.

We don't see Benji leave the room as such... we him stand up (which he would have to do to swap with Solomon), the next time it's just someone who looks like Solomon that we are supposed to think is Benji.

> Also, Walker is watching the room from the laptop.

Certainly that's what we're *meant to think* but we don't actually see Walker viewing the transformation of Benji into Solomon.

It's possible, since the IMF is **clearly on to Walker at this stage**, that they *froze the screen* on what he was looking at so he wouldn't see the swap or, more likely, it's just that he wasn't looking at the laptop during the transformation/swap.

*Mission Impossible* is all about twists and turns so this is just another one we have to take on faith.

In other words, Walker (and the audience) were *meant* to be faked out...they don't have to explain everything.

Comment: I would argue with your first claim. The scene is not cut while Benji transforms. It shows the real Solomon, then spins while Benji is wearing the mask, keeping the real Solomon in the frame the entire time, while Benji leaves the room. Although I think the 2nd claim could be right.

Comment: We don't see Benji leave the room as such...we him stand up (which he would have to do to swap with Solomon), the next time it's just *someone* who looks like Solomon that we are supposed to think is Benji.